# MA Period while on other Chart Types

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to have my MA period be based on regular candles while I'm on other chart types. I already figured out how to set the source of the MA to regular candles on the desired timeframe, but not yet the period. In the example below the '50' must be replaced by a variable that represents the desired period on regular candles:

```
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
realClose = request.security(t, "120", close)
ta.sma(realClose, 50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to calculate the moving average in the context of the 2h timeframe chart with a length of 50 (50 2h bars), directly feed the security function with the ta.sma():

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
realSma = request.security(t, "120", ta.sma(close, 50))
plot(realSma)
```

Comment: Ahh that was the bit of info I needed to complete the code. Thank you!